# Add image to JPanel through JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to add an image from imgur onto a JPanel. The image is not appearing.

```
UTC = new JLabel("test");
utcImg = new ImageIcon("http://i.imgur.com/pkBtKC5.png");
UTC.setIcon(utcImg);
add(UTC);
```

Only the text "test" is appearing. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Thanks

Edit: Adding image from local drive to mitigate latency issues. Now it's not loading. File is in `C:\Users\chg1024\Test\src\images`

```
    JLabel utc = new JLabel("test");
    ImageIcon utcImg = new ImageIcon("images/UTC.png");
    utc.setIcon(utcImg);
    add(utc);
    revalidate();
```

Comment: `" Am I doing this incorrectly?"` -- hard to say given this small snippet. Are you checking to make sure that the Icon isn't null? Are you using layout managers correctly? If this is occurring during run-time, are you calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container that is getting new components?

Comment: As an aside, please read up on and follow Java naming standards. Variable and method names should begin with a lower case letter, classes with an upper case letter, and only constants should be all-caps.

Comment: Most likely it hasn't loaded yet. Use the MediaTracker to monitor when it's done downloading the image and request a revalidation on the panel.

Comment: I'm aware of the naming standards. `UTC` is an acronym. And no, I hadn't heard of `revalidate()` before. I'll try that

Comment: For understandable and shared Java code it should be utc, regardless of if it's an acronym or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ImageIcon(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29) interprets its constructor argument as a file on disk. You could do

```
URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/pkBtKC5.png");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Note however, that loading images from a URL can create issues due to network latency and/or resource availability. An [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) should be preferred instead, for example

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/UTC.png")));
```

Comment: Thanks Reimeus. If that's the case, I will load from file on disk. It's not working though. Please see edit above.

Comment: The image is not where you think it is. `images` needs to be located on the application path

Comment: Okay got it to work by using import wizard. That's weird you can't just add it on your file system to the project in a folder and reference that folder

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this

```
ImageIcon(new URL("write your URL here"));
```